# In Python what type of object does *zip(list1, list2) return?

Tags: python, list, zip, python-3.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Once and for all. What does the Star operator mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/python-once-and-for-all-what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python)

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
zipped = zip(x, y)
list(zipped)

x2, y2 = zip(*zip(x, y))
x == list(x2) and y == list(y2)
```

What type of object does `*zip(x, y)` return?  Why

```
res = *zip(x, y)
print(res)
```

doesn't work?

Comment: The second example doesn't work because it doesn't "return an object".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The asterisk "operator" in Python does not return an object; it's a syntactic construction meaning "call the function with the list given as arguments."

So:

x = [1, 2, 3]
f(*x)

is equivalent to:

f(1, 2, 3)

Blog entry on this (not mine): http://www.technovelty.org/code/python/asterisk.html

Comment: The Python documentation calls '*' in this context an operator, but that's slightly misleading; intuitively, an operator should return an object, but this is really a syntactic construct.

Answer (score 3):

`*zip(x, y)` does not return a type, the `*` is used to [unpack arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) to a function, in your case again `zip`.

With `x = [1, 2, 3]` and `y = [4, 5, 6]` the result of `zip(x, y)` is `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`.

This means that `zip(*zip(x, y))` is the same as `zip((1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6))` and the result of that becomes `[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]`.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` operator in python is commonly known as scatter, it is useful for scatter tuples or lists into a number of variables, and thus is commonly used for input arguments.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Think_Python/Tuples

The double star `**` does the same operation on a dictionary, and is very useful for named arguments!