# Python - asterisk when zipping

Tags: python

I'm a newbie with python and I don't understand why doesn't the following work:

```
ea = zip([[200, 1], [10, 1]])
```

since I'm getting

```
[([200, 1],), ([10, 1],)]
```

while I should add an asterisk like

```
ea = zip(*[[200, 1], [10, 1]])
```

to obtain the result I want, i.e.

```
[(200, 10), (1, 1)]
```

I thought * was meant to convert the list to a tuple, what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have time you can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754453/in-python-what-type-of-object-does-ziplist1-list2-return), it's good resource to understand how `*` works in Python.

The asterisk in Python unpacks arguments for a function call, please refer to [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments)

```
z = [4, 5, 6]
f(*z)
```

will be same as:

```
f(4,5,6)
```

`**` in dictionary does similar work as `*` in list.

Answer (score 3):

`zip` expects multiple arguments, like this:

```
>>> zip([200, 1], [10, 1])
[(200, 10), (1, 1)]
```

If you want to use only one argument, then use the `*` because it has the effect of breaking it up into multiple arguments:

```
>>> zip(*[[200, 1], [10, 1]])
[(200, 10), (1, 1)]
>>>
```

The `*` does not convert lists to tuples. It unpacks lists ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)).

Comment: Thanks, is this the same behavior for asterisk I read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters ??

Comment: That question talks about _defining_ functions with `*` and `**`.  Your question is about using an _existing_ function.  So, it is analogous but not the same.