# What does "gather" mean in computing?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm learning Python.

In "Python For Everyone" by Charles Severance, in the Glossary section for Tuples I came across the following definition:

> Gather: The operation of assembling a variable-length argument tuple.

Right now this is Greek for me, and the vocable isn't mentioned anywhere else in the book I'm learning from. Not even with examples.

I would like to know what does it mean.

Comment: Say you have a number of individual values, and what you want to have a is a tuple that contains those values, so you *gather* the values together into a new tuple.

Comment: I assume this means putting an asterisk in front of an iterable.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/9754453/494134

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They probably mean iterable *packing* or *unpacking* with `*`, but I wouldn't get hung up on the terminology

Simple unpacking

```py
>>> t1 = (1,2,3)
>>> t2 = (4,5,6)
>>> (*t1, *t2)              # unpack two tuples
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> "{}:{}".format(*(1,2))  # unpacking a tuple
'1:2'
>>> "{}:{}".format(*[1,2])  # unpacking a list
'1:2'
>>> "{b}:{a}".format(**{'a':1, 'b':2})  # unpacking a dict
'2:1'
```

More complete example with function arguments
(from [**@Tomerikoo**'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145657/what-does-gather-mean-in-computing/71145761?noredirect=1#comment125764117_71145761), specifically getting multiple args with `*args` (as `'c'` and `'d'` are below) may be what the glossary means by *gathering*)

```py
>>> def foo(arg1, arg2, *args, **kwargs):
...     print(f"{arg1}|{arg2}|{args}|{kwargs}")
...
>>> foo(*('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), foo="bar")
a|b|('c', 'd')|{'foo': 'bar'}
```

`a` and `b` are *unpacked* into `arg1` and `arg2`
.. while `b` and `c` are *packed* into `args`
`foo="bar"` gives a keyword argument, which is *packed* into the `kwargs` dict (as it's not explicitly specified before it)

---

Additionally
If someone discussed *gathering* with me in a Python context, I'd assume they meant [`asyncio.gather()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather), which is not necessarily gathering simple tuples, but a *collection of outputs which may not be immediately available*, though the premise is comparable (and `.gather()` itself takes a variable number of arguments which are packed into its `*aws`, awaitables arg)

Comment: It is more likely means the opposite - *packing*. i.e. `def foo(*args)` packs (or, *gathers*) all arguments passed to it as a tuple, so when calling `foo(1, 2, 3, 4)`, inside the function `args` will be the tuple `(1, 2, 3, 4)`...

Comment: oh, very likely (_how confusing.._) - let me modify my example a little!